# CMD Batch file trouble with nested IF statements and variables

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry

I am writing a cmd batch file which queries windows registry and then reports back to a file with the output. The keys I am looking to query are around SSL for SCHANNEL.

I want the output to read correct and not necessarily the specific reg value, so turning the value into a variable if that variable matches xyz either set another variable to 'disabled' or echo 'SSLv2 is disabled' so rather an interpretation of what the reg value is, for example if 0x1 is the value i want the output to echo 'SSLv2 is disabled' not 'SSLv2 is 0x1'.

I'm having difficult nesting the if statements also if there is no registry key present at all, ie Empty or null to just display 'SSLv2 is enabled'.

Below is just one example for SSLv2 for client side.

```
For /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%a-%%b-%%c)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`hostname`) DO SET hostname=%%F
set hostnamefolder=%~dp0\%hostname%
mkdir %hostnamefolder%\logs
mkdir %hostnamefolder%\logs\files
mkdir %hostnamefolder%\logs\sceenshots
set workingdir=%~dp0

set Logfile=%hostnamefolder%\%hostname%_BRSIS.txt
set curdir=%~dp0
If Exist %Logfile% Del %Logfile%
@echo On
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS

REM ======================================
REM SSLv2 configuration for Client:
REM ======================================

FOR /F "usebackq skip=2 tokens=1,3" %%A IN (`reg query "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server" /v DisabledByDefault 2^>nul`) DO (
    set ValueName=%%A
    set ValueValue=%%B
)

echo %valueName%
echo %ValueValue%

if defined ValueName (
        if %ValueValue% EQU 0x1 (
            echo SSLv2 protocol for client connections is disabled >> %Logfile%
        ) else (
        if %valueValue% EQU 0x0 (
            echo SSLv2 protocol for client connections is enabled >> %Logfile%
        )) else (
            echo SSLv2 protocol for client connections are enabled >> %Logfile%
        )
```

I'm not a programmer so please forgive my coding, however, I'm keen to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if defined ValueName (
   if defined Valuevalue (
     if "%ValueValue%" EQU "0x1" (
        echo SSLv2 protocol for client connections is disabled >> %Logfile%
     ) else (
        if "%valueValue%" EQU "0x0" (
          echo SSLv2 protocol for client connections is enabled >> %Logfile%
        ) else (
          echo SSLv2 protocol for client connections are enabled >> %Logfile%
        )
     )
  ) else (
   echo valuevalue is not defined
  )
) else (
 echo valuename is not defined
)
```

The key is to match indent levels. Your code is missing the terminal `)` to close the outermost `if`. Your `))` closes the *two* inner `if` statements, consequently the `else` is not paired to an `if`.

---

(I'm an ailurophile...)

```
set "message=SSLv2 protocol for client connections are enabled"
if defined valuename if defined valuevalue (
   if "%valueValue%" EQU "0x1" set "message=SSLv2 protocol for client connections is enabled"
   if "%valueValue%" EQU "0x0" set "message=SSLv2 protocol for client connections is enabled"
)
echo %message%>>%logfile%
```

Simple. Or as complex as you need.

Better to clearly say what your desired output is under which circumstances.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting so quickly, thanks also for pointing out my syntax mistake, this only works if the key and value are present, if the key and value are not present it does not work. The first part of the statement does not seem to be working, i.e. if the value of  'ValueName' is not defined or present i would expect the last else statement to be displayed however it does not. The script borks at this point and i recieve the msg '0x1 was not expected at this time'. If the value is present the first part of the statement works.

Comment: OK - fixed to show each branch. I've no idea what you want to do if the values are missing. Note that I've also included "quoting the arguments"` which is best if a string-comparison is performed and you are unsure of the integrity of the values being compared.

Comment: Hi @Magoo thanks for your help on this one, I real appreciate it. This still dosen't work though, i think its close. If the registry key and value are missing completely I want to report it, I want to output to the text file which is what i thought the last else statement was doing. So, we are trying to say, If the ValueName is defined and matches 0x1 echo this.... or if it matches 0x0 echo this..... else (ie if not defined, the key isn't present, echo this....)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example which may help:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "LogFile=Output.log"
Set "RK=HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders"
Set "RK=%RK%\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server"
Set "RV=DisabledByDefault"
Set "SO=SSLv2 protocol for client connections "
Set "DV=does not exist"
For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RK%" /V "%RV%" 2^>Nul'
) Do If "%%B"=="0x1" (Set "DV=is enabled") Else Set "DV=is disabled"
(Echo %SO%%DV%)>"%Logfile%"
```

Here's your code redone with indents and `Rem`arks to help with your learning:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem Ensure this script is in the current direcotry
CD /D "%~dp0"
Rem Setting local variables for use in this script
    Rem Date and time stamps
        Rem Undefine any existing variable named DS
        Set "DS="
    For /F "Tokens=1-5 Delims=/: " %%A In ('RoboCopy/NJH /L "\|" Null'
    ) Do If Not Defined DS (Set "DS=%%A-%%B-%%C" & Set "TS=%%D%%E")
    Rem Hostname
    For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('HostName') Do Set "HN=%%A"
    Rem Host folder
    Set "HF=%CD%\%HN%"
    Rem Log file
    Set "LF=%HF%\%HN%_BRSIS.txt"
    Rem SSLv2 registry key
    Set "RK=HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders"
    Set "RK=%RK%\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server"
    Rem SSLv2 target value
    Set "RV=DisabledByDefault"
    Rem Common SSLv2 output string
    Set "SO=SSLv2 protocol for client connections "
    Rem default SSLv2 output string ending [for missing value]
    Set "DV=does not exist"
Rem Creating necessary directories if missing
If Not Exist "%HF%\logs\files\" MD "%HF%\logs\files"
If Not Exist "%HF%\logs\sceenshots\" MD "%HFr%\logs\sceenshots"
Rem SSLv2 configuration for Client:
    Rem Check registry for SSLv2 key value
    For /F "EOL=H Tokens=2*" %%A In ('Reg Query "%RK%" /V "%RV%" 2^>Nul'
    ) Do If "%%B"=="0x1" (
        Rem define variable for SSLv2 output string ending [for enabled value]
        Set "DV=is enabled") Else (
        Rem define variable for SSLv2 output string ending [for disabled value]
        Set "DV=is disabled")
    Rem Output resulting string to log file
    (Echo %SO%%DV%)>"%LF%"
Rem Rest of code goes here
```

Comment: Hi there thanks for the comment, this also dosen't work if the key and value are not present the script fails. If the key and value are not present I want the script to say so. There needs to be more logic, if the value is null or not present echo this, or if it is present and is 0x1 echo this.... or if it is present and is 0x0 echo this.... thanks for your help though its much appreciated.

Comment: @Abob, I've made a small adjustment to the code to better account for the registry value not existing.